# Using AJAX with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How could I `GET` the information in an XML file and read it into an array on an object so that I'd be able to access it from any function? What's the best way to go about this? I'm using jQuery and AJAX.

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

---

EDIT: Here's some example code of what I have so far:

```
function GetQuestions() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "questions.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                x = 0;
                x = $(xml).find('Questions').length;

                var questionID = $.random(x);

                //Here's where I need to iterate through the questions to find the one with the ID specified by the random var above.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I understand how AJAX works, but I'm a newbie with working with jQuery and I don't know the correct syntax. I have it all worked out in psuedocode but unfortunately that doesn't help. All the same, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('content/file.xml', function(data) {
   // convert to JSON for easier manipulation
}, "xml");
```

As you want to "access it from any function", you'd probably need to convert the XML to JSON.

There is no built-in functionality to do this - you'd need a plugin like the one [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xml2json).

Which also begs the question - why not just return JSON from the server in the first place?

Comment: All I want to do is store the loaded data in an object... was I not clear enough? If that were what I needed, it would work, however. +1

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville - i understand what you want, i just dont understand *why* you want that. If you're going to be working with this data regularly via JavaScript, you need to convert it to JSON. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: In other words - what do you want to do with the object in the javascript?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you misunderstood me again. I am getting information from an XML file and reading it into my JS program. I need to store it in an object, but not convert it or anything, as I already have that covered. I just need to read each variable into one object... perhaps I'd better post some example code.

Comment: Yes - i think so, it's not clear what your trying to achieve. My above answer will do an AJAX GET to a XML file, retrieve it and store it in a variable (data). If you want anything else you'll need to show some code/more clarification.

Comment: Oh... I've misunderstood the code in that case. I thought it was doing something else. That should work. How would I access the information in `data` then? `data.question` or something of that sort?

Comment: Looking at your edited question - my above code is pretty much the same as yours. Is your code not working? Does the `xml` object have data in there?

Comment: If you want to iterate through the `Questions`, you could use `$.find('Questions').each(function() { // do something }` Traverse the XML document the same way you would traverse a XHTML document with jQuery.

Comment: Grr. Yeah, I'm just starting to work with jQuery and AJAX, so thanks for the help. If I could upvote twice I would.

Answer (score 0):

This is as of jquery xml reader .. 
You need to read node by node and insert to array, then to serialize an array to json format with serializeArray jquery function, I didn't check the code , but this is probably what you need.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var mystuff = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sites.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                mystuff = $(xml).find('site');
            }
        });
       var serialized = mystuff.serializeArray()
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$.get('/path/to/file.xml', function(data){
    alert('xml loaded.');
}, 'xml');
```